# 'instaloader' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, instaloader

'instaloader' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

pip install instaloader

instaloader --help

error: 'instaloader' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

earlier it was working but now i'm getting this error

Comment: You will need to find the folder where it was installed and add that to your path. If you use a virtual environment, this should happen automatically when you activate the environment.

Comment: alternatively try `python -m instaloader --help`